# Is instruction pointer a program visible register?

Tags: architecture, x86

I was reading The intel microprocessor 8th edition. I came across the following text:

[image]

> **The Programming Model**
>
> The programming model of the 8086 through Core2 is considered to be **program visible** because its registers are used during application programming and are specified by the instructions. Other registers, detailed later in the chapter, are considered to be **program invisible** because they are not addressable directly during applications programming, but may be used indirectly during system programming.

This gives rise to the thought that all the instructions in 8086 and 8088 are program visible registers, including instruction pointer. Is it so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't touch the instruction pointer directly, but you can get it if you need to with a simple trick:

```
fetch_eip: mov eax, [esp]
           ret
```

Then:

```
call fetch_eip
```

That'll put the value of `eip`, the instruction pointer, into `eax` (because it'll be whatever the stack pointer `esp` was referencing when you call into `fetch_eip`).

It's invalid to have `eip` be the destination of a `mov` operation, so you can't fiddle with `eip` directly. The only way to affect it is with jump operations, call operations (as exploited by this trick), and some other limited cases.

Comment: It's worth noting that on x86-64 you *can* read the value of `rip` directly with `lea rax, [rip]`.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction pointer is a special purpose register, see this article for a list of all the 8086 registers: [Inside the 8086 Central Processor Unit (CPU)](http://www.compeng.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_registers/8086_registers.html)

In general there is no reason for the IP to be "program visible". Its value will be affected by code that uses any instructions that affect control flow such as a `call` or `jmp`. The actual value of the IP should not be required.